# Simple problem on restricted partition

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

When finding number of ways to partition n distinct chocolates among m children such that each child has at most 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\left \lfloor \frac{n}{m} \right \rfloor &  \text{if} \ \ n\ \ \left (mod \ \ m  \right )\equiv 0 \\
\\
\left \lceil \frac{n}{m} \right \rceil & \text{if} \ \ n\ \ \left (mod \ \ m  \right )\not\equiv 0
\end{matrix}\right.$$
How can find the number of unique partitions be found?
For example n=5 and m=3 the answer is 90

Comment: You’re assuming that the chocolates are individually identifiable?

Comment: Yes sir the chocolates are different and distinct.

Comment: @user2307487 in the second condition if will be +1 after floor

Comment: @VidyutVyom : Yes, but $\left \lceil \frac{n}{m} \right \rceil$ is a more concise way of stating it, since $\left \lfloor \frac{n}{m} \right \rfloor + 1 = \left \lceil \frac{n}{m} \right \rceil \ \ \text{when } n \ \ \left (mod \ \ m  \right )\not \equiv 0$ (Just in case this isn't rendering properly again I mean `ceil(n/m)` and not `abs(n/m)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit messy. Suppose that $r$ children get $q+1$ chocolates each, and the remaining $m-r$ get $q$ chocolates each. There are $\binom{m}{m-r}=\binom{m}r$ ways to choose which children get $q$ chocolates. The first of those can get any of $\binom{n}q$ sets of $q$ chocolates; the second can then get any of the $\binom{n-q}q$ remaining sets of $q$ chocolates; and so on. Thus, there are

$$\binom{m}r\binom{n}{q,q,\dots,q}$$

ways to choose and accommodate the $m-r$ children who get $q$ chocolates each, where the [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) has $n-r$ $q$’s.

That leaves $r(q+1)$ chocolates for the $r$ lucky children who get $q+1$ each; they can be distributed in

$$\binom{r(q+1)}{q+1,q+1,\dots,q+1}$$

ways, where the multinomial coefficient has $r$ lower numbers. The total number of distributions is therefore

$$\binom{m}r\binom{n}{q,q,\dots,q}\binom{r(q+1)}{q+1,q+1,\dots,q+1}=\binom{m}r\binom{n}{q,\dots,q,q+1,\dots,q+1}\;,$$

where the last multinomial coefficient has $m-r$ $q$’s and $r$ $(q+1)$’s. In your example of $n=5,m=3$ we have $q=1$ and $r=2$, so this becomes

$$\binom32\binom5{1,2,2}=3\cdot\frac{5!}{1!2!2!}=3\cdot30=90\;.$$

Comment: sir can u please clear a simple thing.how to get q and r
and how to calculate the second term of the solution 
and how many time q and q+1 are repeated in the second term??

Comment: @Vidyut: Those are the same $q$ and $r$ as in my answer to the other question: $q=\left\lfloor\frac{n}m\right\rfloor$, and $r$ is the remainder $n-mq$. In the multinomial coefficients there is a $q$ for each of the $m-r$ children who get $q$ chocolates, and there is a $q+1$ for each of the $r$ children who get $q+1$ chocolates.

Comment: sir can u explain one more thing, in the example n=5,m=3. how did you calculate the brackets (3 2)*(5 1,2,3)
3C2=3
and what after that?

Comment: @Vidyut: It’s in the multinomial coefficient link in the answer: in general $$\binom{n}{k_1,\dots,k_m}=\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\dots k_m!}\;.$$

Comment: in the example you have written 4 that was confusing

Comment: @Vidyut: That was a slip of the finger; I’m glad that you caught it.

Comment: sir i m thankful that u answered